# WHy Gridview doesn't show image ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, webforms

Why Image is not getting loaded in Gridview?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewPropertyDetails" OnRowCommand="grdviewPropertyDetails_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
   <Columns>    
     <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PropertyDetailsFardPath" HeaderText="Fard Path" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height = "100" />
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdDelete" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/delete.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

the path returned is like this

```
G:\Study & Official Projects\Office Projects\Municipal Corporation\MCP-Building Plan Approval\MCP-Building Plan Approval\SiteImages\fard 2.png
```

and yes image is in it but gridview column is empty.

P.S i am saving it into DB like this:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);
    HdnFieldFard.Value = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Image Uploaded", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
    ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
}
```

and

```
string FardImagePath = HdnFieldFard.Value;
```

and then inserted into db by sending FardImagePath

Comment: because you are store only file name in db so how can display image without path? HdnFieldFard is contain only file name not fullpath.

Comment: how to get full path ?

Comment: you can store fullpath + imagename in db.

Comment: I am storing this in DATABASE 

G:\Study & Official Projects\Office Projects\Municipal Corporation\MCP-Building Plan Approval\MCP-Building Plan Approval\SiteImages\fard 2.png

Comment: how can add "SiteImages" folder in your path?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving full path in database. Just save image name in database. And in grid view rowdatabound event you can change image src.

Ex: Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName

Comment: I did what was suggested but now only rectangle box appears in grdivew

Comment: @Covert: rectangle box means blank image?

Comment: Do one thing: Write here what you have written in code. And image name and folder name. I show you how it will work.

Comment: this path is saved 

G:\Study & Official Projects\Office Projects\Municipal Corporation\MCP-Building Plan Approval\MCP-Building Plan Approval\SiteImages\fard2.png

Comment: I am picking this field from db,

PropertyDetailsFardPath

Comment: and assigning it to DataImageUrlField="PropertyDetailsFardPath"

Comment: Do not save full path in database. In some case suppose it will work in your local system but when you change your project folder to another drive or host to server this will not work. Instead of that in row databound event just right as I have written below.

Comment: Image imgName = (e.Row.FindControl("imgName ") as Image);

Comment: imgName.src= Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fard2.png;

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewPropertyDetails"     OnRowCommand="grdviewPropertyDetails_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
  <Columns> 
<asp:templateField>
<itemTemplate>   
 <img src='<%#Eval("PropertyDetailsFardPath")%>' height="100px" width="100%"/>
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdDelete" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/delete.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
</itemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: let me try, sir, wait please

Comment: Path saved successfully but there is a problem with IMAGE, now only a rectangle box is shown gridview, not picture , why ?

Comment: open your browser console and inspect your image tag and check src ? it is correct or not.

Comment: checked, it is like this <img src="" style="height:100px;width:100px;">

Comment: <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PropertyDetailsFardPath" HeaderText="Fard Path" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height = "100" /> in this "PropertyDetailsFardPath" is correct field?

Comment: Give me your db value of PropertyDetailsFardPath.

Comment: G:\Study & Official Projects\Office Projects\Municipal Corporation\MCP-Building Plan Approval\MCP-Building Plan Approval\SiteImages\fard2.png

Comment: <img src="SiteImages/fard2.png" height="100px" width="100%"/>. try this static first and check.

Comment: this time it shows a rectangle but with broken sign, and in html inspect code it show path of image too

Answer (score 0):

```
    Instead you can directly convert the BLOB or Binary in <asp:Image> tag and click on the Button Tag, it will take you to the IndexChangedFunction and you can do further operations with the grid.
Its perfectly worked for me, may be work for your requirement too:

        <asp:GridView ID="Gvid" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gvid_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMAGE" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image runat ="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("IMAGE")) %>' ID="Image"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:ButtonField DataTextField ="MODEL" CommandName="select" HeaderText ="MODEL" />
    </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView>
```